# Is there a way to assemble animation, sound and background image automatically in Flash?

Tags: flash

I'm a total newbie in Flash programming / internals so please tolerate my terminology as you read my question:

I need to learn how feasible it is to automatically assemble Flash animations which take a background image, an animation (or a set of vector drawings that can be turned into an animation) and a sound file from a set of files.

In other words, assume that I have the following set of files:

- 3 background images (let's assume JPG)
- 3 animations (no sound, no static background)
- 100 sound files (let's assume MP3)

So if I want to code something like:

```
for i 1 to 3
  for k 1 to 3
    take animation i 
    take bacground image k
    for j 1 to 100
      take sound_file j
      resulting_swf = assemble (animation[i], background[i], sound_file[j])
      save(resulting_swf)
```

which will produce 900 Flash animations with different combinations of sound and background, what is the starting point?

Are there some libraries (in Python, Perl, PHP, etc.) with good documentation and examples which can help me develop something like that, some program that I can run from the command line?

Comment: You could certainly can embed the assets into a swf using the the mxmlc compiler which comes with the Flex SDK(http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK) using the [Embed] tag and you can access/control those access from actionscript to control the sequencing. Alternatively, you can have a look at swftools (swftools.org/) for handy command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to code anything, just use Flex SDK!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need 900 different swfs? You could just make one swf that dinamically generates different combination of elements every time you run it, effectively giving you all 900 combinations in a single flash file.

Comment: Yes, that's possible in Flash but in my case I need to do this in the context of a Moodle integration project. So either I spend time on hacking a Moodle module from scratch or find a way to package standalone Flash animations which can be easily uploaded into Moodle.

Comment: Without knowing more about the exact nature of the problem you're trying to solve its difficult to be of more help.Anyways, you might look into a scheme of passing arguments to the generic flash anim which would generate the correct combination of elements. Both Flash and Moodle support SCORM which has a well defined mechanism of communicating between the LMS and objects within it. Let me know if that would help.